# how to get executable files of vb.net and access database?

Tags: ms-access-2007, vb.net-2010

I have successfully program a VB.NET 2010 program connected with access database.
I wanna to know how can I run my program on another PC haven't visual studio on it?
what I must copy and how many file are them? and what the extensions of the files? and how can I get these files?

Comment: Pretty basic stuff, Install the NET framework (same or later version used in your dev), Copy your executable and database file and adjust your settings to connect to the database. A little searching effort will be beneficial though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an installation/setup project which will copy and install all the relevant files.

Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project) tutorial for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When a source code is run through visual studio, an executable file is created in the directory of the project. The directory is in the project file **\bin\debug**. You could also find the database there **if connected**.

The program that you are looking for is usually in the extension **.exe**. You also need to make sure that the database is always in the same directory as the .exe file if you will run it on a different computer without visual studio or any other compiler just that the machine is compatible with .exe files (eg. windows OS on machine)